# I try to fetch data from Firebase firestore and i get this error "external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);", why?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, crud

this the code i am using

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
import 'package:moncey2/pages/sensor_details.dart';

class SensorCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const SensorCard({required this.sensorId, super.key});

  final String sensorId;

  @override
  State<SensorCard> createState() => _SensorCardState();
}

class _SensorCardState extends State<SensorCard> {
  String temperature = "";
  String location = "";
  String nomDuCapteur = "";
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getDataFromFirebase();
  }

  void getDataFromFirebase() {
    final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    firestoreInstance
        .collection("sensor")
        .doc(widget.sensorId)
        .get()
        .then((documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        setState(() {
          temperature = documentSnapshot["current_temp"];
          location = documentSnapshot["sensor_location"];
          nomDuCapteur = documentSnapshot["sensor_name"];
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Slidable(
      endActionPane: const ActionPane(
        motion: ScrollMotion(),
        children: [
          SlidableAction(
            // An action can be bigger than the others.
            flex: 1,
            onPressed: null,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
            icon: Icons.favorite,
            label: 'Favorites',
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: ListTile(
        tileColor: Colors.white,
        isThreeLine: true,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          //<-- SEE HERE
          side: BorderSide(width: 0.9),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.sensors,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
        title: Text(
          nomDuCapteur,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 17,
          ),
        ),
        subtitle: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              location,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        trailing: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15, 10, 0),
          child:
              Text(temperature, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => SensorDetails(
                alertHigh: '8',
                alertLow: '2',
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the error that i am getting

```
  @patch
  @pragma("vm:external-name", "Error_throwWithStackTrace")
  external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);
```

can you please help me solve this or tell me what caused it so that i can avoid it.
please note that i am really new to flutter and firebase, and programming in general

i tried to fetch the data from firebase firestore from the sensor collection, using the Document ID  and i wanted to assigne it to the variables declared above to display it in a card

Comment: `Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace)`; is not interesting. That's a function that throws an exception. You need to inspect the stack trace to determine what's calling that function and why.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it I just needed to change this part and add : .toString() like this and it worked just fine :

```
setState(() {
      temperature = documentSnapshot["current_temp"].toString();
      location = documentSnapshot["sensor_location"].toString();
      nomDuCapteur = documentSnapshot["sensor_name"].toString();
```